# How to use POST in Java to get a table?

Tags: java, android, post

I'm making an Android app in java using eclipse.
I want to copy the table of this website http://candea.zermelo.nl/infoweb/index.php?ref=2
On that page is your table with lessons (in dutch)
Before you can see it, you must fil in your Student number (mine is 112224), week and class.

Using network inspector in google chrome, I can see that I have to Post this string

```
"csrf=546820fc781d4b2ccb0c480ad83b6a7f&weeknummer=44&groep=V5B&element_id=112224"
```

For that I'm using this code:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://candea.zermelo.nl/infoweb/index.php?ref=2");
    // Request parameters and other properties.
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "csrf=546820fc781d4b2ccb0c480ad83b6a7f&weeknummer=44&groep=V5B&element_id=112224"));


    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*
     * Execute the HTTP Request
     */

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (respEntity != null) {
            // EntityUtils to get the response content
            String content =  EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
            System.out.println(content);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm not getting the table.
What is wrong?

Comment: The CRSF is a token to prevent the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery attacks, it change each time you reload the page, you can't use the same CRSF for each request

Comment: Thnx. I didnt know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load this page http://candea.zermelo.nl/infoweb/index.php?ref=2, parse it for the hidden input csrf (input type="hidden" name="csrf"), and then post parsed csrf value to the URL that contains Your table.

You need to do these two POST everytime You want to load a table...

Comment: I did exactly what you said and made a Get and extracted the csrf. after that I made a Post with the new csrf. Still no table. What now?

Comment: You should check out what is that You get if not the table. Does it have an error code, or no error, just empty page.

Additionally You are Using the BasicNameValuePair in a wrong way. 
On this page, You can find a code here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: I have done that and I still get the html of http://candea.zermelo.nl/infoweb/index.php?ref=2 as response without anything filled in, just as the GET I use for obtaining the csrf.

Comment: perhaps You should also mimic headers of the request such as Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I added the headers and I get a different response. It is the same, but it stops now at <td id="content>. There is no </body> or </html>.

Comment: It could be that I don't get the full response at once. How could I fix that?